# Ubuntu compare original package and installed parameters

Tags: configuration, ubuntu, installation, dpkg, aptitude

I'd like to compare the actual config files for, let's say, Apache and the ones provided in the original package.

The purpose is to have a list of modifications since initial installation because I didn't document them originally.

I've cruised along dpkg man pages with no success.

Thxs for help Olivier

Comment: I have been looking for tool to do this but I think one does not exist currently. Thus it has to be done manually. If you write a tool for this, please publish it!

Comment: You could start with dpkg -x (extract the original package to temporary directory) and then diff the conffiles.

Answer (score 2):

The file /var/lib/dpkg/info/apache2.conffiles contains a list of the configuration files shipped with the package. Some of them might be generated by a postinst rather than included in the .deb so you will need to compare against a clean install on a different computer, in the general case. Also look out for conf directories containing new files not included in the package. While looking around, also peek into the other apache2.* files in /var/lib/dpkg/info.